# Does binding a method interfere with removing it as an event listener?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I was wondering whether binding a method prevents from removing it as a listener:

```
NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', this.onConnectionChange.bind(this));
```

and

```
NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('change', this.onConnectionChange);
```

Comment: Yes, when removing a handler, it is located by the identity of the function object provided. When you use `.bind()`, you're creating a new, unique function object. So `this.onConnectionChange !== this.onConnectionChange.bind(this)`... and so `.removeEventListener` is looking for the wrong function.

Comment: `bind` creates a new function object. If it was possible to store this reference, then one also is able to remove it ... `var boundHandler = this.onConnectionChange.bind(this)` ... `NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', boundHandler);` ... `NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('change', boundHandler);` - In case this is not possible, one needs to changes the implementation of `this.onConnectionChange`. But then there has more example code to be provided.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind in your constructor with

```
this.onConnectionChange = this.onConnectionChange.bind(this);
```

Now you just send `this.onConnectionChange` directly as the event listener.

Comment: The issue is - it is a base class so I wonder whether the method of the base class or of the subclass will be binded. I need the subclass and I rather avoid .bind(this) in the subclass constructor as it will require a lot of future work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative means of adding listeners that may help. Whatever `this` is, make it implement the *EventListener* interface by adding a `handleEvent` method to its `.prototype`.

```
function Foo {
  // your constructor
}
Foo.prototype.handleEvent = function(event) {
  if (event.type === "change") {
    this.connectionChange(event);
  }
}
Foo.prototype.connectionChange = function(event) {
  console.log("connection changed");
}
```

So then you don't actually pass a function to `.addEventListener`, but rather you pass the instance that implements the interface.

```
// Assuming `this` is an instance of `Foo`
NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', this);
```

So now when `isConnected` triggers the `change` event, it's going to invoke the `.handleEvent` method of the object, with `this` being the `Foo` instance you bound.

And removing the listener is just a matter of passing the same instance.

```
// Assuming `this` is the same instance of `Foo` as above
NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('change', this);
```